# How to add line numbers to textarea only with pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, textarea

How to do that witn Pure JavaScript?

I need clear code or just guidelines.

Comment: The problem is not explained enough. Also there is no evidence TS tried to solve it somehow. No markup, not code-attempts -- nothing. -1

Comment: I guess you should add a <div> to the left of the textarea. Then you can add some numbers to the <div> element.

Comment: I have created a pen about this. You can take a look if you want to - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/CodemasterUnited/pen/oNQexQp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I gathered from your question this what I believe you need. Hopefully it will get you going in the right direction.

```js
var textAreaID = "user-input";

//turn the text area content into an array
var content = document.getElementById(textAreaID).innerHTML.split("\n");

//create array to hold new Content
var newContent = [];

//loop through and add line numbers
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) { //begin for loop


  //append the line numbers and the new value to the newContent array
  newContent.push((i + 1) + content[i] + "\n");


} //end for loop


//update the content of textArea with line numbers
document.getElementById(textAreaID).innerHTML = newContent.join("");
```

```html
<textarea id="user-input" name="user-input" rows="15" cols="40">


      Hello is it working?

      I think so.


</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for that...it's good start. Im gonna develop this by myself